# FFmpeg concat demuxer is changing bitrate

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I am using the concat demuxer to concat some wav files.

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 concat -i files.txt -c copy output.wav
```

files.txt stores files as:

file 'C:\Users\folderpath\input1.wav'

file 'C:\Users\folderpath\input2.wav'

etc

How can I add a -b into this command to set the bitrate? Right now without it, the files are being sped up--input files are 256kbps and output is 705kbps. I've tried several -b and -ab at different parts of the command, and cannot get this to work.

Comment: What are the properties of the two files? `ffprobe file`. Bitrate for WAV files is a simple fixed function = `bitdepth x sampling rate x no. of channels`

Comment: The input properties are:

  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100

  Duration: 00:00:01.15, bitrate: 256 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s

Output properties are: 

  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.2.103

  Duration: 00:00:13.82, bitrate: 705 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s

Comment: Input properties are same for both files?

Comment: No, that was the problem. Thank you!

I had some files that were 256k that were actual sound, and was trying to fill with empty sound using
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:duration=2 silence.wav

the aevalsrc defaults to 44100 Hz, I fixed it by adding a sample rate:
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:duration=2:sample_rate=16000 -acodec pcm_s16le silence.wav

Answer (score 0):

Not all of my input files were 256k, some were 705k so the concat demuxer used the first file, which was 705k.

I fixed it by fixing my input files created by:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:duration=2:sample_rate=16000 silence.wav
```

The key was adding sample_rate to the aevalsrc file--this portion was added after Mulvya's help.

Comment: `the concat demuxer used the largest` --> it will use the properties of the *first* input.

Comment: Edited to change that. Thanks for the help and the correction on the answer.